Как скачать альбом фотографий (медиагруппу) отправленную Телеграм боту Python Aiogram и отправить в ответ сообщение о сохранении фото на сервер
Имеется ТГ бот, у которого есть хэндлер, который скачивает альбом фотографий (медиагруппу) и есть 2 проблемы:

Когда запустил бота на VPS, то не все фото (из 4 сохранялась 1 фотография) из альбома сохранялись в указанную папку, данная проблема наблюдалась только у пользователей, сам я не смог воспроизвести проблему ни локально, ни на VPS.
Необходимо после скачивании всех фото ответить пользователю, что фото сохранены на сервер, в ниже представленном коде отправляется столько сообщений, сколько прислал пользователь фото, а не одно, как это задумано.

    @router.message(Camera_ID.image, F.chat.id.in_(CHATS))
    async def get_image(message: Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
        data = await state.get_data()
        camera_id = data['camera_id']
        file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        file_info = await bot.get_file(file_id)
        file_path = file_info.file_path
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        await bot.download_file(
            file_path,
            f'{ENDPOINT}/{camera_id}/{file_name}'
        )
        await message.answer(
            f'Фотоотчёт к камере {camera_id} загружен.'
        )
        await state.clear()


Звучит как заказ для фриланса

Обычный пет-проект, для рабочих нужд, чтобы упростить себе жизнь и не сохранять фотоотчёт от подрядчика руками и в тоже время бесплатный головняк для меня.

Я к тому, что вопрос составлен как заказ, а не просьба о помощи. Что вы пытались сделать? Что конкретно не получилось?

Первая проблема, как в ответ после сохранения всех фото один раз отправить сообщение о то, что фото сохранены. В выше представленном коде происходит по очередная обработка сообщений с фото, так как при отправке альбома с фото каждая фотография приходит отдельным сообщением и если дописать в конце хэндлера отправку сообщения в ответ, то оно отправляется после каждой сохранённой фотографии

Второй вопрос, как правильно сохранять медиа группы, чтобы все фото точно были сохранены, наблюдалось такое, что из 4 фото сохранялась одна фотография

Обычно это делается через миддлварь. Вам нужно каким-то образом посчитать сколько фото пришло, до обработки каким-либо хендлером. Либо попробуйте использовать библиотеку aiogram album

решил путём добавления middleware слоя:
import asyncio
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message


class AlbumMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.1):
        # Initialize latency and album_data dictionary
        self.latency = latency
        self.album_data = {}

    def collect_album_messages(self, event: Message):
        """
        Collect messages of the same media group.
        """
        # Check if media_group_id exists in album_data
        if event.media_group_id not in self.album_data:
            # Create a new entry for the media group
            self.album_data[event.media_group_id] = {"messages": []}

        # Append the new message to the media group
        self.album_data[event.media_group_id]["messages"].append(event)

        # Return the total number of messages in the current media group
        return len(self.album_data[event.media_group_id]["messages"])

    async def __call__(self, handler, event: Message, data: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
        """
        Main middleware logic.
        """
        # If the event has no media_group_id, pass it to the handler immediately
        if not event.media_group_id:
            return await handler(event, data)

        # Collect messages of the same media group
        total_before = self.collect_album_messages(event)

        # Wait for a specified latency period
        await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

        # Check the total number of messages after the latency
        total_after = len(self.album_data[event.media_group_id]["messages"])

        # If new messages were added during the latency, exit
        if total_before != total_after:
            return

        # Sort the album messages by message_id and add to data
        album_messages = self.album_data[event.media_group_id]["messages"]
        album_messages.sort(key=lambda x: x.message_id)
        data["album"] = album_messages

        # Remove the media group from tracking to free up memory
        del self.album_data[event.media_group_id]
        # Call the original event handler
        return await handler(event, data)

